# Why is $tI - A$ a presentation matrix for the $K[t]$-module $K^n$ via $A$ ($K$ is a field)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

So in other words, I want a surjective module homomorphism from $K[t]^n$ to the $K[t]$-module $K^n$ via the linear operator $A$ such that its kernel is the image of $tI - A$ (viewed as an endomorphism from $K[t]^n$ to $K[t]^n$).

I'm pretty sure I have the first module homomorphism right as I've just chosen the map which sends $e_i$ in $K[t]^n$ to $e_i$ in $K^n$ (so $f(t)e_i$ is sent to $f(A)(e_i)$, etc). I've shown that the image of $tI - A$ is contained in the kernel but how do I show that the kernel is contained in the image of $tI - A$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $K[t]^n \xrightarrow{t-A} K[t]^n \to K^n \to 0$ is exact. This is a special case of the following (with $A=K,B=K[t],M=K^n$):

> Let $A \to B$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings and $M$ be an $B$-module. Then the sequence of $A$-modules $M|_A \otimes_A B \xrightarrow{\phi} M|_A \otimes_A B \xrightarrow{\psi} M \to 0$ is exact, where $\psi(m \otimes b) = mb$ and $\phi(m \otimes b) = mb \otimes 1 - m \otimes b$.

Proof: We have to show that $\psi$ is a cokernel of $\phi$. Let $T$ be some $A$-module. A homomorphism $M|_A \otimes_A B \to T$ vanishing on the image of $\phi$ corresponds to a $A$-bilinear map $\beta : M \times B \to T$ such that $\beta(mb,1)=\beta(m,b)$. This gives a $A$-linear map $\beta(-,1) : M \to T$, and conversely every $A$-linear map $\gamma : M \to T$ gives a $A$-bilinear map $\beta(m,b):=\gamma(mb)$ satisfying the property. $\square$

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I haven't studied tensor products yet though so I was trying to show the exactness of the sequence by directly showing that $im \phi = \ker \psi$. How would you go about it in this way?

Comment: Also, in the general case, why is it a sequence of A-modules? In the special case I had in mind that all modules in the sequence were K[t]-modules.

Comment: I doubt that you get such a sequence of $B$-linear maps. If you want that, the module on the left has to be $M \otimes B \otimes B$. Actually more generally there is a long exact sequence with the modules $M \otimes B^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: I think I've found a source which directly addressed what I was talking about. http://mathwanderer.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/rational-canonical-form/
The proof of Claim 1 was what I was wondering about